# Sending POST from node.js - how does a website identify me?

Tags: node.js, cookies, authentication, request

there is a website that works with virtual items for an online game. I made a chrome extension that automates some actions on that website. Since I'd like to make this run on my raspberryPi (and chromium with the extension seems to be too slow and unefficient) I am trying to move this into node.js.

The login for the website works with Steam OpenID. It allows you to select items from a list, click a few buttons, then it sends you a tradeoffer on steam.

My extension works with the website while I was logged in there. It receives their database with jQuery getJSON, loops through the array, pushes some values into an array and then sends a post request telling the website which items I want and which items I am offering.

Here is how I am sending the request from chrome:

```
function withdrawXHR(botId, playerItems, botItems) {

    $.ajax({
        url: websiteURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            "steamid": botId,
            "peopleItems": playerItems,
            "botItems": botItems
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.error('>> Done: ' + data)
            console.log("")

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('>> Error: ' + errorThrown)
            console.log("")

        }
    });

}
```

I can do everything in node so far like receiving their database, working through it, filter out the values I need, but I can't manage to send a working request. The problem is probably the login / how the website knows who I am.

I used wrapAPI (a chrome extension) to catch the request that is being sent when manually working with the website. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Request]

So these are the things I am wondering about:

- How would I send this request from node?
- How does the website know who I am? They obviously know, because they are sending me an offer, but I can't see any "personal" data in that request.
- Would I need to log into Steam OpenId from Node in some way? Is that possible?
- What is a CF-RAY? (See the end of the captured request).

I am quite new to JS and requests in general and even "newer" to Node.js. I don't fully understand how the background of sending requests works. I would just need some tips, ideas on how to achieve my goal here.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use XMLHttpRequest for resources across domains. ( incidentally, unless you are using an extension)

I would look into grabbing express.js, and something called CORS. CORS permits cross-domain requests.

Here: http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

And here is some information on XHR requests in browser extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: I think you got me wrong here. The extension was only running on the website itself, so there is no cross domain requesting. The extension also worked flawlessly. What I am trying to achieve is to get rid of the extension and move all my actions to Node.JS. For this to work, I would need to find out how to identify myself with the website from Node since I can't see anything like a cookie being transmitted with the request. Thanks a lot for the link, will read through that and see if I can work with it! :)

Comment: Are you adding headers?

Comment: So far - no. The short piece of code at the top is what I was using to send the request from chrome. The headers were done by chrome itself I think. If I would send the request from node, would I need to add all those headers manually? If so - I can't see any information that is used to identify myself in the headers of the example request I attached with the image.